# AWS Elatic Beanstalk and rails: pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.13) in file header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to shift from heroku to amazon aws and after I dumped the db using:

```
heroku pg:backups:capture
heroku pg:backups:download
```

I ran:

```
eb ssh
cd /var/app/current    
pg_restore -v -h $NAME.$ID.$DATACENTER.rds.amazonaws.com -U $RDS_ROOT_USER -d $DATABASE_NAME latest.dump
```

I get the following error:

> pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.13) in file header

BTW I am using rails.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which postgres version are you using?

Comment: @AbhishekKushwaha 9.2.4

Comment: I fell into same situation, upgrading your postgres version of RDS  instance will fix this issue.

Comment: @AbhishekKushwaha I selected the RDS instance and updated the postgres version to 11.4-R1 and tried again but it didn't work

Comment: Are you getting the same error? If not, please put your error here.

Comment: @AbhishekKushwaha Yes, I am getting the same error.

Comment: What postgres version you were using on heroku ?

Comment: @AbhishekKushwaha 10.7

Answer (score 0):

You're using an old version of **pg_restore** binary that doesn't support restoring the provided dump file. Please make sure that you use the latest Postgres version, which must be higher than the following release: https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1834/ (10.3, 9.6.8, 9.5.12, 9.4.17, and 9.3.22).

You can check the **pg_restore** version you're using by running **pg_restore --version**.

If you are using a third-party tool, such as PgAdmin, to restore the provided dump file, the restore may not succeed even with the installed Postgres version being up to date. This is due to third-party tools often bundling their own versions of the **pg_restore** binary, that may not be up to date.

Follow this link: [Why am I getting pg_restore](https://help.heroku.com/YNH1ZJUS/why-am-i-getting-pg_restore-archiver-unsupported-version-1-13-in-file-header-error-with-pg_restore)